# Generate string with same initial 5 characters of SHA1 hash with given string

Tags: python, sha1

i have a given string, let's say 'test123'
i calculate the sha1 hash value of the string with and take the first 5 characters:

```
sha1(teststring.encode("utf-8")).hexdigest()[:5]
```

now i want to generate a random string that has the same first 5 sha1 hash characters

```
''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation) for _ in range(16))
```

i have a working solution were i just generate random strings and hash them until i find a matching one.

is there a faster way to achive this?

Comment: think that this related question will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859100/convert-sha1-back-to-string

Comment: [random.choices](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/random.html#random.choices) should be a bit faster than repeated calls to random.choice.

Comment: `hexdigest()` does not give you bits, it gives you a string, where each letter represents a hex values ("0" through "F" to mean numerical 0 through 15). So if you slice off the first five of those, you now have five letters, representing 20 bits.

Comment: You could utilize the fact, that a small change to the string will result in a completely different hash. So you don't need to create a new random string each time.

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't anything beside brute force.

SHA-1 is a cryptographic hash function, and your question is very close to the matter of finding collisions.

Finding a faster way than brute force would defeat the purpose of SHA-1. Have a look at the wikipedia article, it's pretty well documented.